# Merging two pandas dataframes, how to avoid duplication of axes with the same name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It's possible that I don't completely understand what all the arguments to `pandas.DataFrame.merge` do, but for a simple example of what I'm after:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(0,100), 'b':np.linspace(0,10,100)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(1,101), 'b':np.linspace(0.1,10.1,100)})
# Additionally both the above have some other irrelevant columns
# which don't share the same name

df = df1.merge(df2, on='a', how='outer')
```

The column `'a'` is an integer and what we want to actually fuse on. However, since `'b'` is present in both DataFrames, in the result it will get duplicated into `'b_x'` and `'b_y'`. Is there any simple option to make prevent that? What I would want instead is that `df` has one single `'b'` column, which takes its values from `df1` in cases where that row was present in `df1`, but from `df2` in cases where it wasn't present in `df2`.

The reason I want that is in cases where `'b'` is potentially a float, and I'd expect it to be *essentially* the same in both dataframes, but I might not be able to guarantee I have exact floating point equality.

I guess it could be done with boolean indexes, with first a merge with `how='left'`, and then filling in the rest:

```
df = df1.merge(df2['a',...], on='a', how='left')
df[df.a.isin(df1.a)]['b'] = df1.b
df[~df.a.isin(df1.a)]['b'] = df2.b
```

but is it possible to use any of the arguments in `pd.merge` to do the above directly.

Comment: If I understand correctly, would this not work: `df = df1.merge(df2, on=['a', 'b'], how='outer')` ?

Comment: True, but there may be cases where for the same `'a'`, the two `'b'` could be different since they are floating point numbers, and depending on the route to calculate or produce them, they may have that minuscule variation between their values, whatever it's called. It feels a bit uncomfortable to merge on floats no?

Comment: are we talking about `10.0000000000000001 == 10.0` ? if so, as well as being unlikely, that is an entirely different question/solution.

Comment: Yes that could be one case. Or for example, if I'm merging multiple dataframes, and in some cases 'b' is a string representation of a float since it was read from a file, that sort of thing. The more I think about it, the more it sounds like there's no point in there being a solution to this, either your suggestion or the full manual way with boolean indexing should be the proper way.